# Batch for execute Putty, log on Server and run commands with shell script or txt

Tags: ssh, unix, shell, putty

I need help for this process. I have a batch file to run Putty and log with ssh an server and will execute commands from file "commands.txt".

```
C:\Programme\PuTTy\putty.exe -ssh user@server -pw 123456 -m c:\Programme\PuTTy\commands.txt -t
```

in the command.txt file i will run this commands:

```
sudo su - newUser
cd /Scriptfolder
./start.sh
```

My batch runs to switsch user and stopt. The batch switch not in the newUser Folder

Thanks for reply

Comment: Whats the actual question?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28197540/best-way-to-script-remote-ssh-commands-in-batch-windows May help a bit.

Comment: I need a batch file for start putty, open ssh to an server and execute commands from script file to start an ./serverStart.sh

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question, you want to do something like this in command.txt:

`sudo su - newUser -c /Scriptfolder/start.sh`

or depending on your sudoers config

`sudo -u newUser /Scriptfolder/start.sh`

Comment: This dosen´t work... i get the answer:
usage: sudo [-D level] -h | -K | -k | -V
                                        usage: sudo -v [-AknS] [-D level] [-g groupname|#gid] [-p prompt] [-u user
                                              name|#uid]
                                                        usage: sudo -l[l] [-AknS] [-D level] [-g groupname|#gid] [-p prompt] [-U user
                                                                 name] [-u user name|#uid] [-g groupname|#gid] [command]
                                        usage: sudo [-AbEHknPS] [-r role] [-t type] [-C...

Comment: There was a mistake in "sudo -u newUser -c /Scriptfolder/start.sh", as sudo does not accept "-c". So I edited my answer. I tested the first an second line and both work. The test was realized on CentOS. Which system do you use ?

Comment: when i type "sudo -u newUser /folder/" the answer is "sudo: /folder: command not found?

Comment: "folder" is a folder. You have to cd in the folder or call your command with full path as in my example.